# Why is [^@] regular expression acting the way it does?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was looking for a regular expression to validate e-mails when I found this:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

The `[^@]` expression seems not to work like the documention says it should.

```
s = 'test'

match = re.match("[^@]", s)

print(match.group())
```

This for example prints the first character of the string that is `t`.
If i use regular expression `[^]` I get an error: `unexpected end of regular expression`. The documentation says that:

> Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets.

`[]` is a set and `^` is a special character.

Comment: Make sure to appropriately title questions. The `[^@]` expressions works *exactly* as it is documented to, and a case has not been made otherwise; it is the `[^]` expression that throws the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement "special characters lose their special meaning inside sets" is true because the caret character has *two* special meanings; at the logical start of a regular expression (where it is an anchor), and at the start of a character class ([or 'character set' where it forms a 'complementing set of characters'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)).

The reported error comes from the `[^]` construct which is invalid since the character class is not closed: the `^` affects the next character(s).

In this case the effect is the `]` does *not* close the character class and the entire regular expression is "not ended", resulting in the regular expression syntax error.

---

Anyway, the error reported about `[^]` has nothing to do with `[^@]` which is a character class that will match any character *except* `@`. This, coupled with the incorrectly focused title, probably explains some of the downvotes..

```
re.match("[^]",  "anything")  # => regex error, as explained above
re.match("[^]]", "z")         # => match; z is not ]
re.match("[^@]", "z")         # => match; z is not @
re.match("[^@]", "@")         # => no match
```

Answer (score 1):

The character `^` is a special character.

```
^Test ... matches a string that starts with Test
   \^ ... matches the character ^
 [\^] ... matches the character ^
 [^^] ... matches a character that is not a ^
 [-^] ... matches a - or a ^
 [^-] ... matches a character that is not a -
[\^-] ... matches a - or a ^
```

Comment: This question is more about _why_ the caret behaves the way it does, rather than what the expression means.

Answer (score 0):

`[^]` is a special case. It means "match a single character that is not in the brackets." Have a look at [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) for more detail.